# Input blur not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, blur, onblur

I am trying to add a .success class to an input field whenever I click out of the input field. However, when I click off of the input the .required class is still showing even though I have removed the class. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('#legal_name').focus(function () {
    $('legal_name').removeClass('whiteBorder');
    $('#legal_name').addClass('required');
});
$('#legal_name').blur(function () {
    $('legal_name').removeClass('required');
    $('legal_name').addClass('success');
});
```

Comment: You forgot the `#` in `$('legal_name').removeClass('whiteBorder');` Now it is looking for a node like this: `<legal_name></legal_name>` which it does not find.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.


Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo

```
$('#legal_name')
   ^ missing id-selector
```

[**#** id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

---

or better use

```
$('#legal_name').focus(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('whiteBorder').addClass('required');
}).blur(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('required').addClass('success');
});
```

[this-keyword](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

Comment: user error as always ;) thanks for the suggestion to write shorter code too!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing # signs.

```
$('#legal_name').focus(function() {
    $('#legal_name').removeClass('whiteBorder');
    $('#legal_name').addClass('required');
});

$('#legal_name').blur(function() {
    $('#legal_name').removeClass('required');
    $('#legal_name').addClass('success');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to add `#` in `$('legal_name')`

Try add `$('#legal_name')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#legal_name').focus(function() {
$('legal_name').removeClass('whiteBorder');
$('#legal_name').addClass('required');
});
$('#legal_name').blur(function() {
$('#legal_name').removeClass('required');
// ^ your id identifier '#' is missing
$('#legal_name').addClass('success');
// ^ same here
});
```